# r fread: how to read txt with no separator

Tags: r

I have a txt like

0010

1101

1110

and I hope to fread() txt into data frame like

0 0 1 0

1 1 0 1

1 1 1 0

although fread() + strsplit() could do this, applying it to >1M row takes too long. Is there a way to tell fread() to directly split each row into single character/integer? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tsrtsplit` from `data.table` instead, which gives a nice speed boost.

```
library(data.table)
raw <- sample(1000:9999, size = 100000, replace = TRUE)
writeLines(as.character(raw), con = "tst.txt")

# Tom Kelly's suggestion
system.time(tmp1 <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(readLines("tst.txt"), ""))))

# user  system elapsed 
# 19.280   0.522  22.109 

# with tstrsplit
system.time({
  tmp2 <- fread(file = "tst.txt", colClasses = "character")
  tmp2[, c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4") := tstrsplit(V1, split = "")]})

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.089   0.002   0.099 

# read.fwf
system.time(tmp3 <- read.fwf('tst.txt', rep(1, 4)))

# user  system elapsed 
# 1.308   2.301   3.666
```

Comment: I'd suggeste using `DT[, paste0("var", 1:length(tstrsplit(DT$V1, ""))) := tstrsplit(V1, "")]` for the splitting, so you do not have to type all column-names by hand.

Comment: yes, depending on the input data it might be better to define it beforehand, to not have to run `tstrsplit()` twice. Or maybe use something like `max(nchar(V1))`

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by `data.table::fread` as mentioned in the documentation.

> ```
> sep: The separator between columns. Defaults to the character in
>      the set ‘[,\t |;:]’ that separates the sample of rows into
>      the most number of lines with the same number of fields. Use
>      ‘NULL’ or ‘""’ to specify no separator; i.e. each line a
>      single character column like ‘base::readLines’ does.
> ```

Calling `data.frame::fread` doesn't do this.

```
> data.table::fread("test.txt", data.table=FALSE, sep="")
    V1
1 1001
2 1101
3 1011
```

For example `readLines` will read as a vector and `strsplit` will return a list.

```
> readLines("test.txt")
[1] "1001" "1101" "1011"
> strsplit(readLines("test.txt"), "")
[[1]]
[1] "1" "0" "0" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "1" "0" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "1" "0" "1" "1"
```

As data.frame is a list where each element is a column so you need the transpose of this.

```
> t(as.data.frame(strsplit(readLines("test.txt"), "")))
                      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
c..1....0....0....1.. "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
c..1....1....0....1.. "1"  "1"  "0"  "1" 
c..1....0....1....1.. "1"  "0"  "1"  "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read this as fixed-width file to get every character as separate column.

```
data <- read.fwf('temp.txt', rep(1, 4))
```

You can also look into `readr::read_fwf` which is more faster than `read.fwf`.